# Make the bootstrap dropdown arrow change direction on click anywhere else inside the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the following example [Code Ply](http://www.codeply.com/go/0bQbyG4zdO), I can make the arrow in the dropdown to be disappear when the button is clicked (dropdown items is shown) and appear when button is clicked again (dropdown items is hidden), but when I clicked anywhere else, the dropdown items is hidden, but the arrow is not appear, until I click the button again, then the arrow is appear.

How can I trigger the javascript function whether arrow is appear or disappear based on the dropdown items is shown or hidden?

Your answer much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want the arrow facing UP when you have opened the dropdown?

Comment: Hi, I already can make the arrow facing up when the dropdown menu is shown, and make the arrow facing down when the dropdown menu is hidden. (I am not sure why it didn't show correctly on the codeply, it only show hidden or shown). What I cannot do right now is, the dropdown is only change when I click the button itself, but not when I click anywhere on the screen (where the dropdown menu is hidden also when I do that)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `caret-up` class manually you could use the `.open` class of the bootstrap dropdown (check it out in the inspector, click the dropdown and you should see the change) and style your arrow according to that

Could look somewhat like

```
.dropdown.open .caret
{
    //dropdown is open
}

.dropdown:not(.open) .caret
{
    //dropdown is not open
}
```

no need for own css at al

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this below code snippet.
Detect click anywhere outside of dropdown, and if the `span` doesn't have the `class caret` add it.

```
$(document).click(function() {
   if(!$(".dropdown").find('span').hasClass("caret"));
        $('span', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
});
```